# Automatically Passing WCF headers from Service to Service

Tags: wcf, header

We have and app that is using custom headers to pass what we call a "callerid". The caller is just a way of identify which customer is calling the service, so we can connect them to the right db etc. At the moment we have 3 services which all require the callerid to function.

so a call might be

```
callerid --> callerid --> callerid
Service1 --> service2 --> service3
```

what we are doing at the moment is reading in the header at every call and re attaching it before every new call.

But some calls might not need the callerid

so the call could look like

```
callerid ---------------> callerid
service1 --> service2 --> service3
```

is there a wcf way to automatically reattach the headers at service2?

cheers

Johnny